# Calling a python script over HTTP

Tags: python, http, tomcat, web

I have a python script `script.py` that generates an HTML file `page.html`. The page is then moved to a tomcat server roughly at this path:

```
tomcat/webapps/myscript/page.html
```

I would like to add an HTML button to the page that allows me to launch the script again and refresh the page. How could I configure tomcat to do this?

**Technical environment**

- Python 2.7
- Tomcat 7.0.19
- Solaris 10

Comment: any special reason why not do the page producing, fetching etc using python wsgi. or building on it a micro web framework like bottle or flask?

Comment: flask is a great suggestion but if you have to use tomcat then you should use jython not python.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1, The file generate by a python script. So the problem is who to execute

```
python script.py
```

by Tomcat

2, Tomcat is servlet container, so you can create Process by java to do that:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /DIR_FOR_SCRIPT/script.py");
proc.waitFor();
closeProcess(proc);
```

Note: The user for Tomcat need authority to execute the commend.

3, You can put code in step 2 in a jsp or servlet. 
when access that, it generate the new version file.

4, That also is MVC pattern. The data is not from database, is from a script.
But they both are same.